# type hints for method annotated with @property

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you access type hints for methods annotated with the @property decorator?

Normally, this is very straightforward:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self) -> str:
...             pass
... 
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Foo.bar)
{'return': <class 'str'>}
```

But once `bar` is annotated with `@property` and made into a property object, it's not obvious:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @property
...     def bar(self) -> str:
...             pass
... 
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Foo.bar)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1527, in get_type_hints
    'or function.'.format(obj))
TypeError: <property object at 0x1050fcc28> is not a module, class, method, or function.
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Foo.bar.__get__)
{}
```

Comment: The [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) class documentation mentions the attribute you want, but only briefly near the end: "The returned property object also has the attributes fget, fset, and fdel corresponding to the constructor arguments.".

Comment: [related discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/594#issuecomment-440355134) on the python/typing repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `__get__` isn't the actual function, but a wrapper around it:

```
>>> Foo.bar.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of property object at 0x11d6f3b88>
```

To access the function, you use `property.fget`:

```
>>> Foo.bar.fget
<function __main__.Foo.bar>
```

And of course that has the annotations:

```
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Foo.bar.fget)
{'return': str}
```

That isn't exactly obvious or discoverable. IIRC, this came up at some point on python-ideas—it's relatively easy for Mypy or another outside static analyzer to get the annotations for a `property`, but not for code inside the program—but I assume nobody came up with a good answer, or it would have been implemented (or at least discussed in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)).

Answer (score 1):

The function you defined is `Foo.bar.fget`, not `Foo.bar.__get__`:

```
typing.get_type_hints(Foo.bar.fget)
```